# Differentiate home button pressed, back button pressed and new activity launched

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity`. Within its `onPause` function, I would like to differentiate

- Home button pressed
- Back button pressed
- Launching a new activity (This will cause the fragment activity's `onPause` being called)

For *back button pressed case*, I know I can differentiate it by using `this.isFinishing() == true`.

However, how about *launching a new activity case*?

I know perhaps I can set a flag before launching the new activity, and reset the flag, at the end of `onPause` function. But, it doesn't sound elegant to me. Is there any better and robust way?

Comment: One pointer is, I think, to also handle `onStop()`. However, as stated this problem is ambiguous - what are you really trying to do? Does "launching" include switching to a background task that had actually been terminated then restarted by the system, for instance?

Comment: I think u can override key events So that u can determine Home or back pressed

Comment: You cannot override the home key press.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class that tracks when your activities start/resume/pause/stop. Make a base Activity class that calls the singleton in each of its lifecycle callbacks.

If you look at the order of the callbacks when transitioning between activities, you should see this:

```
Pause Activity A
Create Activity B
Start Activity B
Resume Activity B
Stop Activity A
```

When your singleton gets called from Activity A's onStop(), you can check if there was a call from onResume() from another Activity (which clearly belongs to your app). If there wasn't, you know the user has changed apps or gone back to the home screen.

As for the back button press, you can check `isFinishing()`, or override `Activity.onBackPressed()` and do your bookkeeping there.